# Toggle div on input field focus

Tags: html, focus, toggle

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
     <ul>...</ul>
</div>
<div id="header-search">
     <input id="search-input" type="text" />
</div>
```

When the input field is focused, I need it to hide the "navigation" div and then make it reappear when the text field is no longer focused.

I've tried multiple times to accomplish this through CSS which would be easier than Javascript but with no success.  A fade effect would be nice as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showNav(show) {
  if (show) {
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
<div id="header-search">
     <input id="search-input" type="text" onblur="showNav(true)" onfocus="showNav(false)"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with jquery, a superset of javascript. You can learn about it (and download the .js files) at http://jquery.com

or you can do with with 'straight' javascript like this:

```
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hideNav() {
            var nav = document.getElementById("navigation");
            nav.style.display = "none";
        }

        function showNav() {
            var nav = document.getElementById("navigation");
            nav.style.display = "";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
     <ul><li>something</li><li>something else</li></ul>
</div>
<div id="header-search">
     <input id="search-input" type="text" onfocus="hideNav();" onblur="showNav();" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your fade effect and manipulating these and other dom objects gets a lot easier with jquery, but this will get you moving for now..

**edit** after your comment that the transition is too 'snappy' I thought to offer this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
<div id="navigation">
     <ul><li>something</li><li>something else</li></ul>
</div></div>
```

by wrapping the navigation div in an outer div that is of fixed size the other elements on the page won't "jump around" when the navigation div becomes hidden. doesn't give you your fade, but does provide a cleaner UX. Of course, your mileage may vary. As for why the jquery didn't work, I am not sure without more of what you tried.

Comment: So using jquery's .fadeToggle: 

`<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#search-input").click(function() {
   $("#navigation").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
 });
</script>`
...nothing is happening.  I'm sure it has to do with it being an input field and focusing instead of just clicking.

Thank you for the quick responses. The straight javascript works great it just seems too "snappy" for what I'm wanting it to do.